# addEventListener doesn't work in flash 17

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, addeventlistener

i have a small app for resizing images "agile uploader". it worked fine until i upgrade my flash player up to 17. now this part of code doesn't work.

```
var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
        button.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
        button.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        button.graphics.endFill();
        button.useHandCursor = true;
        button.buttonMode = true;
        button.mouseChildren = false;
        button.name = "browse";
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _handleMouseEvent);
        addChild(button);

    private function _handleMouseEvent(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)ExternalInterface.call("alert", 2);
        switch ( String ( evt.target.name ))
        {
            case "browse" :     
                if(this.file_limit == 0) {
                    _fileRef = new FileReference();
                    _fileRef.browse([this._fileFilter]);
                    _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, _onImageSelect);
                } else {
                    _multiFileRef = new FileReferenceList();
                    _multiFileRef.browse([this._fileFilter]);
                    _multiFileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, _onMultiImageSelect);
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

i know that there are no errors in this part of code but it still doesnt work in flash player 17.

i compile app in flash develop. flex 4.6.0 as default sdk.

if someone knows what's wrong please tell me!

any help appriciated!

Comment: How do you determine that `addEventListener` doesn't work?

Comment: You click the button and nothing happens?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that a new flash player would break `addEventListener`.

Comment: Well, my point is that "nothing happens" doesn't really isolate the problem very well. I doubt that `addEventListener` is the problem, it's something else. Put some debugging output, or better, run the SWF with a debugger and see where it gets to.

Comment: the first function that shold be executed after click is ExternalInterface.call("alert", 2); but nothing happens. if i run swf with the debugger evering works well! BUT!!!! my debuger version is 10.3.0 and browser has 17

Comment: It's very probably because ExternalInterface throws you a SecurityError that you are not catching. You should always call a js method/func in a try/catch block, it is not enough to check whether the ExternalInterface is available!

Comment: Have your tried putting a trace statement as the first line of the click listener?  Likely an error is being thrown and the function is exiting before reaching your switch.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to your ExternalInterface call.  In the Flash embed code, make sure allowscriptaccess=always.